# Prevent auto-scroll to top on orientation change in a XF ScrollView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Rather annoying issue, but it seems as though there's some default behavior on a scroll view, that when you change orientation, it auto-scrolls to top. `ShouldScrollToTop` is a property available on a `UIScrollView` but doesn't seem to be available in a XF ScrollView. But it does it anyway? Is there a way to stop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a quick test on this and only found it to be an issue on iOS. On Android the ScrollView did not scroll to the top after rotation. I did not test UWP/WinPhone. If it is iOS only, a bug should be filed against Xamarin.Forms.

In the meantime, here is a workaround for iOS. You will need to create a custom renderer [1] for your ScrollView. And the renderer code would look like this:

```
public class MyScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
{
    CGPoint offset;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        UIScrollView sv = NativeView as UIScrollView;
        sv.Scrolled += (sender, evt) => {
            // Checking if sv.ContentOffset is not 0,0
            // because the ScrollView resets the ContentOffset to 0,0 when rotation starts
            // even if the ScrollView had been scrolled (I believe this is likely the cause for the bug).
            // so you only want to set offset variable if the ScrollView is scrolled away from 0,0
            // and I do not want to reset offset to 0,0 when the rotation starts, as it would overwrite my saved offset.
            if (sv.ContentOffset.X != 0 || sv.ContentOffset.Y != 0)
                offset = sv.ContentOffset;

        };
        // Subscribe to the oreintation changed event.
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this, new Selector("handleRotation"), new NSString("UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"), null );
    }

    [Export("handleRotation")]
    void HandleRotation()
    {
        if (offset.X != 0 || offset.Y != 0) {
            UIScrollView sv = NativeView as UIScrollView;
            // Reset the ScrollView offset from the last saved offset.
            sv.ContentOffset = offset;
        }
    }
}
```

[1] https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

Comment: I know what a custom renderer is, but this looks great. I'll definitely try it tomorrow and check if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have extended @jgoldberger's answer and come up with this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView), typeof(MyApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.Controls.FieldStrikeScrollViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.Controls
{
    public class MyScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        CGPoint offset;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            UIScrollView sv = NativeView as UIScrollView;
            sv.Scrolled += (sender, evt) => {
                // Checking if sv.ContentOffset is not 0,0
                // because the ScrollView resets the ContentOffset to 0,0 when rotation starts
                // even if the ScrollView had been scrolled (I believe this is likely the cause for the bug).
                // so you only want to set offset variable if the ScrollView is scrolled away from 0,0
                // and I do not want to reset offset to 0,0 when the rotation starts, as it would overwrite my saved offset.
                if (sv.ContentOffset.X != 0 || sv.ContentOffset.Y != 0)
                    offset = sv.ContentOffset;

            };
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            if (offset.X != 0 || offset.Y != 0)
            {
                UIScrollView sv = NativeView as UIScrollView;
                // Reset the ScrollView offset from the last saved offset.
                sv.ContentOffset = offset;
            }
            base.LayoutSubviews();
        }
    }
}
```

but he's right, this should really be fixed by Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with those answers in the newest Xamarin version. They will cause issues with the scroll offset behaviour when they keyboard is shown/hidden. The Scrollview might stay in an invalid offset position and can't be scrolled down by the user anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to add a new seperate answer. In the later version of Xamarin.Forms (3.0+)

this is a better fix:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView), typeof(MyApp.iOS.CustomRenderers.Controls.ExtendedScrollViewRenderer))]
namespace FieldStrikeMove.iOS.CustomRenderers.Controls
{
    public class ExtendedScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {

        public override CGSize ContentSize 
        { 
            get => base.ContentSize;
            set
            {
                if (Element is ScrollView scrollView)
                {
                    if (!scrollView.ContentSize.IsZero && value != scrollView.ContentSize.ToSizeF())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                base.ContentSize = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Linked to this [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3112)